# A free utility for NTFS writing on Mac OS X 10.6.5?

Tags: macos, filesystems, ntfs, compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy files to read-only NTFS hard drive on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/338607/how-to-copy-files-to-read-only-ntfs-hard-drive-on-a-mac)

Coming from Windows (Vista/7), I have a few NTFS formatted Hard Drives.

Are there any programs to make OS X write to NTFS?

Do I have any options aside from installing Windows via Boot Camp and reformatting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. [NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/). You will need to do a bit of hunting to find the free and open source NTFS-3G as opposed to the commercial Tuxera NTFS, which they will quite cheerfully sell you. The latest link at time of writing is on that page under "NTFS-3G for Mac OS X 2010.5.22". I'm not sure if NTFS-3G includes it, but you may also need to install [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/).

Comment: Note that some of the paid programs like Tuxera are also faster and more stable.

Comment: I found the link on their site, it's the other post under `October` in the sidebar. Also, for the record, according to the site NTFS-3G includes MacFUSE. I'll try to test it later, just installed remotely, unfortunately, the drives seem to be turned off right now.

Comment: We have a winner!

Answer (score 1):

If you have macports installed you can install it quickly and freely.  It's available.

```
$ port search ntfs
ntfs-3g @1.5130 (fuse)
    Safe read/write NTFS driver for FUSE

$ sudo port install ntfs-3g
```

If you want to use other tools you can install ntfsprogs and you will be able to resize, etc.  ^^

Comment: I'm not a fan of these kinds of add-ons (macports, wine etc) but I think I'll give this a go.

Comment: I found the GUI installer as per Scott's answer. See my comments there.