# How to delete files from NTFS formatted external drive using OS X?

Tags: macos, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A free utility for NTFS writing on Mac OS X 10.6.5?](https://superuser.com/questions/176978/a-free-utility-for-ntfs-writing-on-mac-os-x-10-6-5)

I have a 1TB external hard drive that I think is formatted for Windows (NTFS?) but I have a Mac.

Right now I can view the data on there but I can't delete any of it.

Is there something I can do to be able to change the format to be able to delete stuff without removing any data and totally reformatting the external hard drive?

Comment: Heh, I misread the title to mean "how can I delete data without losing it?"

Answer (score 8):

Just install [NTFS-3g for OS X](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/2010/10/ntfs-3g-for-mac-os-x-2010102.html) on your Mac and be done with it.  It's a read/write NTFS driver for your Mac.

Comment: Heh, you beat me :P

Comment: NTFS-3G has been working for me for over a year. Seems very stable and easy to install.

Answer (score 4):

There is [NTFS-3G for OS X](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/ntfs3g.html), which is a Freeware driver that allows you to also *write* to NTFS-formatted volumes.

**Caution:** Use at your own risk.