# How to copy files to read-only NTFS hard drive on a Mac?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, ntfs

I want to copy my some files from Mac (Macbook-Air) to an USB external hard drive, formatted as NTFS.

How is it possible? Because when I do copy my files from the Mac and go to paste them on the external HD there is no option for paste.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check out this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/447/how-can-i-use-ntfs-partitions-in-os-x

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that your drive is NTFS formatted. OS X can't write NTFS out of the box (at least not without some tweaks). Here are some ways to do this.

### Format the drive as FAT-32

This is the obvious answer to those who don't want to install software that potentially could harm their data (which is always the case with hacks / unstable software). Re-format the drive to FAT-32, which both Windows and OS X can read and write out of the box.

This is of course *not* a solution for files larger than 4GiB.

### NTFS-3G via Homebrew installation

If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), installing NTFS support is as easy as running the following in a terminal:

```
brew install ntfs-3g
```

Then, follow the instructions on the screen. Homebrew will tell you how to replace the default OS X automounter so external NTFS drives are mounted using the new driver. Those are a couple of commands you need to run through your terminal.

### NTFS-3G via GUI installation

This is a free version (there's also a paid one, and the free one's a bit harder to find).

- First, download and install [Fuse for OS X](https://osxfuse.github.io/) and select the MACFUSE compaibility layer during the install.
- Then, download [NTFS-3G](https://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/2010/10/ntfs-3g-for-mac-os-x-2010102.html), a free NTFS driver. Download the latest version [from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/catacombae/files/NTFS-3G%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X/) and install it.
- You will have a new option in *System Preferences* that enables you to write to NTFS drives.

  [image]

### Commercial solutions

These are *not* free, but offer support and promise better speed/stability.

- [Tuxera NTFS for Mac](https://web.archive.org/web/20200814174045/https://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/)
- [Paragon NTFS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/)

### Hacks

- There is [SL-NTFS](https://v4.s.arclk.net/api/user/01b7676142293178f1462c092611a11747368d6a77.r?tk=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwdWIiOiI1MjJjNjE1YTlhODQ4MGNhYjhiMTA0MTIiLCJ0cyI6IjA4MDEwNTQ1IiwiZCI6ImNvY29hYnlzcy5jb20ifQ.pHLw6kvpRj4FLvJdPNQYKiWBPPrNAPoW8UkN0O4RMbs), which isn't maintained anymore, but promises to enable NTFS write support on Snow Leopard (10.6).

  > Because SL-NTFS is basically an interface for configuring the Apple NTFS driver, any issues you might encounter will be related to the Apple driver rather than SL-NTFS. If you require a more robust, supported solution for writing to NTFS drives/partitions, I recommend you locate a more comprehensive solution.
- This is [a hack for enabling NTFS write support](https://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090913140023382) on OS X 10.6 which involves some command line tweaks. Again, use it at your own risk.

---

#### Related Super User questions

I felt those were lacking an overview of tools:

- [A free utility for NTFS writing on Mac OS X 10.6.5?](https://superuser.com/q/176978/48078)
- [How to access external HDD with NTFS from my iMac for free?](https://superuser.com/q/222367/48078)
- [How to delete files from NTFS formatted external drive using OS X?](https://superuser.com/q/299760/48078)

Answer (score 4):

Get the latest version of MacFuse first from [here](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse).

After you install it, you will need to install [ntfs-3g](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/2010/10/ntfs-3g-for-mac-os-x-2010102.html). This is the FUSE. You will need to make sure you have the latest versions of both, since older versions of ntfs-3g might not work with a newer version of MacFuse.

You should now be able to read AND write from your Mac to any NTFS drive.

Comment: Note: MacFuse is no longer under development.

Answer (score 0):

## Q. How to copy files to read-only NTFS hard drive on a Mac?

## A. Enable NTFS write on the drive.

#### There are some excellent instructions on [osxdaily.com](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/).

---

Michael Dreher points out in the comments of the preceding osxdaily.com link:

(referring to [this](http://opensource.apple.com//source/ntfs/ntfs-83/kext/ntfs_vfsops.c) source code)

> We only allow read/write mounts if the "nobrowse" option was also
>         given.  This is to discourage end users from mounting read/write,
>         but still allows our utilities (such as an OS install) to make
>         changes to an NTFS volume.
>    Without the "nobrowse" option, we force
>         a read-only mount.  Note that we also check for non-update mounts
>         here.  In the case of an update mount, ntfs_remount() will do the
>         appropriate checking for changing the writability of the mount.
>
> if ((vfs_flags(mp) & MNT_DONTBROWSE) == 0 && !vfs_isupdate(mp))
>           vfs_setflags(mp, MNT_RDONLY);

--

## Tested: Solution is confirmed working on everything from Maveriks to El Capitan.

About El Capitan:

> De says:   September 10, 2014 at 10:10 am
>
> If the other solutions don’t work – the following does a 100%:
>
> mkdir ~/Desktop/Drive // where the drive will be mounted mount // will
>   tell you the internal drive name, something like /dev/disk2s1 sudo
>   umount /dev/disk2s1 sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,nobrowse
>   /dev/disk2s1 ~/Desktop/Drive Reply
>
> Jo says:
>       The only solution that worked perfectly, thanks !
>
> ```
> gia says:
> Excellent solution, works for NTFS in OS X El Capitan and OS X Yosemite
> ```

---

### The site I referenced is very rich with all kinds of troubleshooting and debugging scenarios.

I won't try to re-create it.  Before starting, reading through the article and the comments would be good to do, notably the later ones that deal with El Capitan.

### Keep track of your permissions.

Make an NTFS folder (on the NTFS drive) to transfer into that has the least restrictive settings (read/write/update for everyone).  Once you've had success you can try out more restrictive options.

### Caution:  Be very careful with syntax when using fstab.

There is confusion with users of OS X because apple removed their fstab file.  You simply need to create one.

- I've created a fstab files on El Capitan.  It works well.

### Fastest and "proper" solution.

- This solution can make all your NTFS drives automount the way you want.
- This solution can also give you access to the rest of the powerful mounting features of fstab.
- No 3rd party software.
- This solution (controlling the fstab file) is very portable.  Fstab itself is a very common standard in computing among *NIX machines, from UNIX, OS X, BSD, Linux..  and dates back to [Unix V8](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/5/fstab) at the latest.  (+ 31 years).

---

#### Additional references:

[Fstab file detailed info and explanations (linux flavor).](http://www.linfo.org/etc_fstab.html)

[Fstab wiki info.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab)

[man fstab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab)

---

## A2.  You could also install OSXfuse via Homebrew.

This is a common third party solution.

Here are instructions on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152661/write-to-ntfs-formated-drives-on-yosemite)