# How do I read and write to NTFS drive on Mac OS Lion

Tags: macos, ntfs

I have tried the following solutions without success:

- [Paragon NTFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/)
- [Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/)
- http://osxfuse.github.com/
- http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/2010/10/ntfs-3g-for-mac-os-x-2010102.html

All of them allow me to see my NTFS external hard drive but none of them let me write to it. Actually, Paragon NTFS works until I plug the drive into a Windows Machine. Then I can't use it on my Mac without reformatting and Tuxera NTFS worked for a day then went into read only mode. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

After trying multiple things, I found something that worked for me. I have Paragon NTFS installed. After formatting my harddrive to NTFS and adding files from my mac I plugged it into a Windows Machine. When I plug that same drive back into my mac it doesn't recognize it anymore unless I go into Disk Utility and repair the hard drive. This takes about a minute and leaves all files intact. Kinda a pain but it works for me needs.

Comment: Related: [How to Copy Mac files to external NTFS hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/338607/how-to-copy-mac-files-to-external-ntfs-hard-drive/338618#338618)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; Teach a man to fish and
>   you feed him for a lifetime

Now, let us learn to do this for free.

Before we start. Make sure your external name label is **ONE** word.
That means there is no space in between.

my disk = **WRONG**

my_disk **or** my-disk **or** mydisk = **CORRECT**

## Now

1. Open Terminal [<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+"terminal"]
2. Type: `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
3. In nano, type: `LABEL=my_disk none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse` Note: **my_disk** is **your** disk name
4. To save and exit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. **[optional]** For ease of access, we create a sym-link to desktop: In terminal -> `sudo ln -s /Volumes ~/Desktop/Volumes`

## Later

When you don't need it anymore. It is as simple as:

In terminal `sudo rm /etc/fstab`

Done.

Comment: I want to warn anyone - while this solution works, the drive mounted this way will often have errors. It won't happen every time, but when it does, you'll need to fix the drive (for instance by plugging it in the Windows machine). I haven't experienced data loss this way, but I prefer other solutions.

Comment: You should warn about `sudo rm /etc/fstab`it could be dangerous ...

Answer (score 5):

I am currently using Tuxera NTFS http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/ and can read and write to NTFS devices as small as 1GB to 3TB in Mac OS and then plug them into Windows with no issues.

I think the issue you are facing is that Mac is not picking up the correct driver.

- After you have installed Tuxera, you can check in Settings => Tuxera NTFS and it should say Tuxera NTFS status: Enabled.
- In your NTFS drive, is there a folder .Tuxera-NTFS and the file disable-driver?
- When you plugin your device, does your Console (logging) application show any errors?

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G).

Assuming that `brew` in installed correctly :

```
$ brew cask install osxfuse
$ brew install ntfs-3g
```

Now, create the following folder :

```
$ sudo mkdir /Volumes/NTFS
```

You must identify the logical name of your harddrive, `diskutil list` will help you. In my case I found out that the disk I want to mount is called `disk2s1`.

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/NTFS -olocal -oallow_other
```

Oups !

```
Error opening '/dev/disk2s1': Resource busy
Failed to mount '/dev/disk2s1': Resource busy
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.


$ sudo umount /dev/disk2s1
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/NTFS -olocal -oallow_other
```

Now it works but you will have probably the following message : 
[image]

Allows the system software *Benjamin Fleischer* to do it's job and execute again :

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/NTFS -olocal -oallow_other
```

You should see something like that in your Finder window now :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [OSX FUSE](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse) paired with NTFS-3G.

Installation is fairly simple - first install OSX FUSE, then NTFS-3G. Follow [installation instructions on OSX FUSE site](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G).

This is a free solution which has never caused me any trouble (i.e. data or filesystem corruption). On the other hand, some other solutions (like simple `/etc/fstab` edit) had break my filesystem in the past.

Answer (score 0):

2020 and I still looked for the answer. Then I found [Mounty](https://mounty.app/) app worked for me out of the box, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

NTFS-3G provides detailed instructions on its [Wiki](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G) which has worked for me on a couple of different Macs already.

```
# unmount if necessary
sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk1s1
# mount with ntfs-3g
sudo mkdir /Volumes/NTFS
sudo /usr/local/bin/ntfs-3g /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/NTFS -o local -o allow_other -o auto_xattr -o auto_cache
```

(Use `diskutil list` to find the name of the NTFS partition).

Answer (score -2):

exFat.
Free and already an option
Tuxera costs money.
I was also using Tuxera til it broke down on me.
exfat works on both Windows and Mac machines.

Comment: The author already tried Tuxera it didn't work for him.

Comment: I believe he is suggesting to format the hard drive as exFAT. That is a valid idea... but there are a number of downsides to that format. The biggest one being no allocation table so if you unplug at the wrong time your data will get messed up.