# Toshiba external hard drive is read-only on MacBook

Tags: external-hard-drive, macbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Copy Mac files to external NTFS hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/338607/how-to-copy-mac-files-to-external-ntfs-hard-drive)

I have a Toshiba external hard drive that works fine when connected to my Dell Windows 7 laptop and also to my Ubuntu desktop.  However when I connect it to my MacBook, the drive is read-only.... the Create Folder and Paste options in the finder are disabled whenever I have the external hard drive open.  How can I make it writable on the MacBook?

Answer (score 2):

You need a driver for the Mac to enable it to write on a NTFS disk such as NTFS-3G