# Why did NTFS-3G via Homebrew stop working?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, ntfs-3g

I followed the directions [here](https://superuser.com/q/338607/9461):

> ### NTFS-3G via Homebrew installation
>
> If you have [Homebrew][5], installing NTFS support is as easy as
>   running the following in a terminal:
>
> ```
> brew install ntfs-3g
> ```
>
> Then, follow the instructions on the screen. Homebrew will tell you
>   how to replace the default OS X automounter so external NTFS drives
>   are mounted using the new driver. Those are a couple of commands you
>   need to run through your terminal.

And it worked perfectly at first, but a couple days later now and when I insert a USB drive that worked before, it is mounting as read-only.

How can I get NTFS-3g working again?  I tried reinstalling the homebrew, but it stated that it was already installed and did nothing.  Should I uninstall and reinstall, if so, how do you uninstall a homebrew item?

Comment: You can try `brew remove ntfs-3g` and then install again. No need to completely remove Homebrew though. Make sure you follow the instructions where you have to copy a file over—this is needed to have OS X automatically mount drives in write-mode.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have the instructions anymore, perhaps that would be sufficient, but lacking that, I will remove and reinstall to get the instructions again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NTFS-3G asks you to replace /sbin/mount_ntfs with their own version. If it stops working, then probably is because an OS X update replaced that file.

To fix this, you must do the following:

1. Rename the mount_ntfs command provided by OS X:

   `sudo mv /sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs.original`
2. Make sure the mount_ntfs command provided by NTFS-3G is used:

   `sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs`

Comment: Can you please explain what these command do?

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide a little more detail